# How does The Switch Initially Works

Tags: networking

I want to ask question about the Ethernet Switches , lets consider a switch with 8 ports only , and I want to set up  a local are network of 8 PCs, if I want each PC to communicate with each other, and I plug in  the whole PCs with the switch and turned it on , How does the switch will initially know the mac address of each PC network card ? I think there must be a memory in the switch that should inform the switch how to transmit  the frames from PC x to the others PCs and PC y to the others and so on . 
Can you please clarify this point .

Comment: This is not programming specific. Please use another stack exchange site. But in general You are right. There is a mapping table which deals with holding pairs of macs and their assigned ips.

Comment: ok , there's no other stack exchange for my question , the site said I should ask a supervisor or Network Engineering .
Thanks ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple.

Because the ethernet frames have 48 bit address fields, it is obvious that switch should know the MAC address of the destination PC.

For this ,switch uses address resolution protocol. When a sender wants to send data to a receiver with given IP address but does not know its MAC address, it is used.

In this, the table stored inside switch is checked for the IP address. If one of the entries match, then the switch forwards the frame to the port mentioned in the table. If it does not, it broadcasts a request message that asks every host who has this IP?.

The host on the LAN will respond if the IP address given in the request message matches its IP address and will send a unicast reply to the switch informing its MAC address. Then switch updates the table and sends the frame on appropriate port.

Comment: make sense, but one thing not clear , isn't the IP in this context is the MAC address you meant? because as far I know the IP related to the routers (Network layer ) . and the Switch doesn't have the Network layer .

Comment: Thats what switches are meant for. The switch on getting the link layer address(MAC) forwards it to the link layer of the corresponding link.

Comment: yup that what I thought ,but they have nothing to do with the IP right?